# unexpected output by applying overloaded subscript operator

Tags: c++

I overloaded subscript operator[] for my array, and in my main function when i try to test it i got confused and didn't get the output that i expected to. I expect 0, 0, 0, 0 but i got 16, 9, 4, 1!
Here is my program:

```
//  main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

class Arr{
private:
    int a, b, c, d;
public:
    Arr(){a = b = c = d = 0;}
    int &operator[](int index){
        switch (index) {
            case 1:
                return a;
            case 2:
                return b;
            case 3:
                return c;
            case 4:
                return d;
            default:
                throw range_error("bad index");
        }
    }
};

int main(){

    Arr arr;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        arr[i] = i * i;

    for(int i = 4; i > 0; i--)
        cout << arr[i] << ", ";
}
```

Comment: why do you expect zeros when you set the values before printing them?

Comment: because i assigned zero to the parameters a, b, c and d in the constructor, and in the operator[] function i returned them

Comment: what is this line doing ?  `arr[i] = i * i;`

Comment: arr[1] = 1 .  arr[2] = 4 . arr[3] = 9 .  arr[4] = 16

Comment: erm.. yes. I suggest: change that line to `arr[i] = i*2;`, think for a moment what output you expect now and run the code again

Comment: Do you realize now?

Comment: No surprise in the generated output. See https://ideone.com/bzVdSL

Comment: you mean that in operator[] function for example by returning d "return d;" i actually returned a[4]???

Comment: no, `return d;` means: return a reference to the member `d` , so when you assign to the reference you actually assign to the member

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your `main` function you create an object `arr` of class `Arr`. At this point the constructor is called and the member variables `a, b, c, d` are set to `0`. Next, in the `for` loop the member variables `a, b, c, d` are set to `1, 4, 9, 16` because the `operator[]` method returns a reference (`int &`) to the member variables. This means, that `arr[1]` is a reference to the member variable `a`. When `arr[1]` is changed, `a` is changed, too. In the next `for` loop the values are printed in reversed order.